# character to binary conversion in C++ two characters at a time to get 16 bit binary form

Tags: c++, binary, char

Hello i want to convert two characters at a time in a string to binary? how can i do that by applying simple arithmetic (that is by making my own function?)

For example: our string is = `hello world`:

Desired output (two characters at a time):

```
 he       // need binaryform of 0's and 1's (16 bits for 2 characters 'h' and 'e'
 ll       // similarly
 o(space) // single space also counts as a character with 8 zero bit in binary.
 wo
 rl
 d(space) // space equals a character again with 8 zero bits
```

how to go about with it. i dont want any ascii in between. directly from character to binary...is that possible?

Comment: Characters are already stored in binary (naturally) internally. What exactly do you need? Should 'he' become 'eh' to conform endianness for little endian as 16-bit pairs? Or do you want to see 'he' in binary form as a string?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misunderstood the assignment and weren't asked to output the binary value of *unicode* characters (which are 2 bytes wide)?

Comment: If you explain the problem you are trying to solve it may be easier to understand the question.

Comment: What do you intend to do when your string has an odd length? You forgot to consider this in your little thought experiment... by the way, there is no way to go from character to binary without passing through something like ASCII first. This is because you have to define your original character encoding scheme before you can even begin to re-encode it...

Comment: sorry i guess i've missed out on something here...i know characters are already stored in binary...i just want those 'binary values' of my string to be concatenated n stored in an array...16 bits at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to *textually* represent the binary representation of characters, then here's a small example of how you can do it:

A small function that prints out the binary representation of `c` to `std::cout` (will only work for standard ASCII letters):

```
void printBinary(char c) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << ((c & (1 << i))? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```

Use it like this (will only print out pairs of characters):

```
std::string s = "hello "; // Some string.

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += 2) {
    printBinary(s[i]);
    std::cout << " - ";
    printBinary(s[i + 1]);
    std::cout << " - ";
}
```

Outputs:

```
01101000 - 01100101 - 01101100 - 01101100 - 01101111 - 00100000 -
```

**Edit:**

Actually, using `std::bitset` this is all that is needed:

```
std::string s = "hello "; // Some string.

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += 2) {
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(s[i]) << " ";
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(s[i + 1]) << " ";
}
```

Outputs:

```
01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000
```

If you want to store the binary numbers of the character pairs in a `std::vector`, as mentioned in a comment, then this will do it:

```
std::vector<std::string> bitvec;
std::string bits;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += 2) {
    bits = std::bitset<8>(s[i]).to_string() + std::bitset<8>(s[i + 1]).to_string();
    bitvec.push_back(bits);
}
```

Comment: how should i edit this to save my string s 16 bits at a time in an array instead of cout-ing it on screen?

Comment: @user899714 You probably forgot to include the header: `#include <vector>`.

Comment: yes i didnt. thanks! how do i see it...and where are these 16 bits being saved exactly? in bitvec? i want to use these bits ahead too actually.

Comment: @user899714 `bitvec` should contain 3 `std::string` elements, each representing the 16 bits of the respective character pairs. You can access the elements as with a raw array, e.g. `std::string firstElement = bitvec[0];`.

Comment: @user899714 To access the individual bits you could use `bitvec[i][j]` etc.

Comment: oh that makes it simpler, u mean if is use bitvec[0] that would be the first 8 bits of my string? or 16 i guess?

Comment: so if i want the first 8 bits that would mean accessing them in a vector array of length i by j?

Comment: @user899714 If you want the first 8 bits of the first element then you could do `bitvec[0].substring(0, 8)`.

Comment: one last thing, where should i create the member substring?

Comment: @user899714 I don't understand what you mean with "member substring", but I guess where you need it. Also there´s a typo in my previous comment it should be `substr`, not `substring`.

Comment: if i want sum all the binary string like this (16 bits + 16 bits + 16bits...)i need to know the length of my bitvec right? how do i find that out?

Comment: @user899714 `bitvec` is a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) so use `bitvec.size()` to get the number of elements.

Comment: can you help with adding the 16 bits that are concatenated in 'bits'. every time a set of 16 bits is concatenated, i want them to be added (binary addition) to an array...till all sets of 16 are complete in my string. If there is an overflow, length of final sum >16...then add that extra bit to the final sum as 0000000000000001 (where 1 is the 16th bit).

Comment: @Snps could you please explain what that does (c & (1 << i) ? its part of your first solution.

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis This is a bitwise left shift operation and a bitwise AND operation (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). Basically I check the bit at each position in the binary representation by using AND on the shifted 1. E.g. `00000001 << 5 == 00100000`, and `01100001 & 00100000 == 00100000` (now I know the 5th bit from LSB [zero-based numbering] is `1`). The question mark is used as a ternary operator which is basically a short hand for if/else.

Comment: @Snps thank you for the explanation. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished quickly and easily using the **bitset** class in the C++ STL.

Below is a function that you can use:

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

string two_char_to_binary(string s)   // s is a string of 2 characters of the input string
{
    bitset<8> a (s[0]);    // bitset constructors only take integers or string that consists of 1s and 0s e.g. "00110011"
    bitset<8> b (s[1]);    // The number 8 represents the bit depth

    bitset<16> ans (a.to_string() + b.to_string()); // We take advantage of the bitset constructor that takes a string of 1s and 0s and the concatenation operator of the C++ string class

    return ans.to_string();
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string s = "hello world";
    if(s.length() % 2 != 0)    // Ensure string is even in length
        s += " ";

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i += 2)
    {
        cout << two_char_to_binary(s.substr(i, 2)) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not directly return `a.to_string() + b.to_string()`?

Comment: That should be good enough as well, but I put in the extra bitset to avoid any funny business.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the thing you're looking for is casting. Try like this:

```
char *string = "hello world ";
short *tab = (short*)string;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    std::cout << tab[i] << std::endl;
```